# etree destroy the file

Tags: python, xml, svg

I want to edit svg file with xml.etree.ElementTree. I've got the code:

```
tree=ElementTree.parse('file.svg')
tree.write('file2.svg', xml_declaration=True)
```

But unfortunately file2.svg looks very different and can't show it in viewnior, whereas file.svg looks fine in viewnior.
Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What are the changes in edition?

Comment: Thanks for reply. There's no change, this is whole code.

Comment: Perhaps file.svg is damaged.

Comment: It is output of Inkscape and I don't think so. You can check it out here: http://janknizek.cz/kresba.svg and output: http://janknizek.cz/output.svg. I see in Firefox it works (not in my imageviewer), but the source code is very different.

Comment: Etree does not destroyed your file (at least because this [image](http://janknizek.cz/output.svg) correctly displays in the browser), it simply re-format image. Basically the problem is in the viewnior, that it can't displays such images not in the etree.

Comment: That is true, but there is big reformat of the file (for example path to ns0:path). Is it possible to get rid of these changes?